# How to done Pagination in CodeIgniter using style classes of Bootstrap

Tags: php, codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap, pagination

I know to work with CodeIgniter Pagination Library.
But It is Confusing to Work with Bootstrap Pagination classes.
Please help me.
if Possible give me an example.

Comment: check out this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20088779/bootstrap-3-pagination-with-codeigniter

Answer (score 2):

CodeIgniter pagination class is really cool, but I was having a hard time integrating it with the twitter Bootstrap CSS framework, it was something like an extra dozen config parameters while initializing the pagination library, so I had to modify the CodeIgniter pagination class to be compatible with Bootstrap.

I created a new file under application/libraries/ folder and called it MY_Pagination.php

[CodeIgniter Pagination Integrated with Bootstrap](http://draco-003.com/blog/archives/2013/10/07/CodeIgniter-Pagination-Integrated-with-Bootstrap/i-32)

Comment: Please give me some simple example. I am new to This.

Comment: plz check link that i provided

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php if(!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('Direct Access Not Allowed');

/* This Application Must Be Used With BootStrap 3 *  */
$config['full_tag_open'] = "<ul class='pagination'>";
$config['full_tag_close'] ="</ul>";
$config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
$config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$config['cur_tag_open'] = "<li class='disabled'><li class='active'><a href='#'>";
$config['cur_tag_close'] = "<span class='sr-only'></span></a></li>";
$config['next_tag_open'] = "<li>";
$config['next_tagl_close'] = "</li>";
$config['prev_tag_open'] = "<li>";
$config['prev_tagl_close'] = "</li>";
$config['first_tag_open'] = "<li>";
$config['first_tagl_close'] = "</li>";
$config['last_tag_open'] = "<li>";
$config['last_tagl_close'] = "</li>";
```