# paging in codeigniter with bootstrap

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter, pagination, paging

I have a problem with my online shop program, i would like to show all my product Based on brand name, so i will show the product list when visitor choose one of brand name. i successfully show my product base on brand name. and the product i set 15 per page. its work. But the paging is always active in page No. 1 although i click page no.2 , page No. 1 was active but the product change to Page No. 2 Listing. i Think that the problem is in controller but i do not where is exactly. This Is

my **Controller :**

```
function manufacture($manufacturing_name = null,$offset=0)
{
 $config['base_url'] = base_url().'listing/manufacture/'.$manufacturing_name;

        $config['total_rows'] = $this->m_listing->list_num_rows($manufacturing_name);
        $config['per_page'] = 15; /*Jumlah data yang dipanggil perhalaman*/
        $config['uri_segment'] = 3; /*data selanjutnya di parse diurisegmen 3*/

        /*Class bootstrap pagination yang digunakan*/
        $config['full_tag_open'] = "<ul class='pagination pagination-sm' style='position:relative; top:-25px;'>";
        $config['full_tag_close'] ="</ul>";
        $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['cur_tag_open'] = "<li class='disabled'><li class='active'><a href='#'>";
        $config['cur_tag_close'] = "<span class='sr-only'></span></a></li>";
        $config['next_tag_open'] = "<li>";
        $config['next_tagl_close'] = "</li>";
        $config['prev_tag_open'] = "<li>";
        $config['prev_tagl_close'] = "</li>";
        $config['first_tag_open'] = "<li>";
        $config['first_tagl_close'] = "</li>";
        $config['last_tag_open'] = "<li>";
        $config['last_tagl_close'] = "</li>";

        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        $data['halaman'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
        $data['offset'] = $offset;
        $data['data'] = $this->m_listing->view($config['per_page'], $offset,$manufacturing_name);
 $this->load->view('theme/listing',$data);
    }
```

My **Model :**

```
function list_num_rows($manufacture_name)
    {
        $this->db->from('product');
        $this->db->join('manufacturing','manufacturing.id_manufacturing = product.id_manufacturing','left');
        $this->db->where('manufacturing.manufacturing_name',$manufacture_name);
        $sql= $this->db->get()->num_rows();
        return $sql;
    }

    function view($num, $offset, $manufacture_name)
    {
        $this->db->join('manufacturing','manufacturing.id_manufacturing = product.id_manufacturing','left');
        $this->db->where('manufacturing.manufacturing_name',$manufacture_name);
        $this->db->order_by('launching','desc');
        $query = $this->db->get("product",$num, $offset);
        return $query->result();
    }
```

My **View :**

```
<div class="product-listing row">
                    <?php  $no = $offset;
                    foreach($data as $row ) { ?>
<div class="product__inside__price price-box"><?php echo $row->type ?></div>
<?php } ?>
</div>
<div class="filters-row__pagination">
                                <?php echo $halaman ?>
                        </div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [bootstrap 3 pagination with codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20088779/bootstrap-3-pagination-with-codeigniter)

Comment: Its not work, always Page No. 1 is active

Comment: @GustiErlangga change this `$config['cur_tag_open'] = "<li class='disabled'><li class='active'><a href='#'>";` to this and check `$config['cur_tag_open'] = "<li class='disabled active'><a href='#'>";`

Comment: @AbdullaNilam. Page No. 1 Is always Disable

Comment: @GustiErlangga check added answer

Answer (score 0):

**FYI**

This is what I use for Pagination.

```
  // style
  $config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination">';
  $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
  $config['first_link'] = false;
  $config['last_link'] = false;
  $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
  $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
  $config['prev_link'] = '&laquo';
  $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="prev">';
  $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
  $config['next_link'] = '&raquo';
  $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
  $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
  $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';
  $config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';
  $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="#">';
  $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
  $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
  $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
```

Comment: its Not Work, I was copied

Comment: did you add without adding any changes?

Comment: $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="#">'; change to this  $config['cur_tag_open'] = "<li class='disabled active'><a href='#'>"; ?

Comment: yes, i was copied all code that you post, but the result its same

Comment: i was added .htaccess file